# SQL Server multiple databases security question

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server instance with two databases:

Database 1 is locked down so no users can access the data, only admins can access (I'm an admin)

Database 2 is wide open to all domain users. There's one table on database 1 that I would like to make available to users that have access to database 2. Obviously I would create a view in database 2 based on the table in database 1, but only admins would be able to select on said view. Is there a way to grant access so users can select from the view on database 2 without having access to database 1? I'm just wondering if there's something I could design or set up to accomplish this task. I hate to replicate the same data on database 1 to database 2. Granting users access to database 1 is not an option either.

Comment: You could give the other users permission to database 1 but only with rights to select from that one table. If they need access to that specific data, then give it to them, but don't grant permission to any other parts of the database. Otherwise you're just doing arbitrary ring-fencing ("this database is for admins"...except that isn't true any more) for no practical reason.

Comment: It might be good to create a specific schema in `Database1`. This way, if there are other tables (or views or SPs) down the line that you want other users to have access to, just assign them to that schema.

Comment: Both good ideas, thanks!!

Comment: you can also create a service account; and share with only specific users that are going to access DB1 to only have select permission; on DB1. Putting in own schema depends how hard dba(s) are in specific org.